# addResourceHandler @EnableWebMvc setup

Tags: spring-mvc

My handler was working prior to some dependency updates and ditching of the XML in my app. But now I get this error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /resources/img/logo.png
```

My view resolver is working fine, my controller is pointing to the right places it is just my css/js that doesn't seem to map.

```
public class ConfigClass {
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

    return viewResolver;
}

public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WebMvcConfigurationSupport** appears to be essential.

```
 public class ConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport{
    //Rest here
    }
```

> EDIT

The initial answer was based on an amateur "cached" answer. The actual solution was using

```
public class ConfigClass extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
```

However, this is now deprecated. Am looking into an answer for that.